# Excluding rows based on certain conditions in corresponding columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I'm trying to exclude certain rows based on certain conditions:
Criteria A - exclude if imm1 or imm 2 = bio1 or bio2 (i.e. would exclude row 1)
Criteria B - exclude if imm1 or imm 2 = surg (i.e. would exclude row 2)

meta_CD (name of data frame)

| Row no | imm1 | imm2 | bio1 | bio2 | surg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2009 | 2010 | 2010 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 2004 | NA | 2015 | NA | 2004 |
| 3 | 2009 | 2009 | NA | NA | NA |
| 4 | 2015 | NA | NA | NA | NA |

Just wondered how I would do this in R please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `!(df$imm1==df$bio1 | df$imm2==bio1)`

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:
To exclude rows if imm1 not in list bio1, bio2, you can use:

```
meta_CD <- meta_CD[! meta_CD$imm1 %in%('bio1','bio2'),]
```

To add imm2:

```
meta_CD <- meta_CD[! meta_CD$imm1 %in%('bio1','bio2') | ! meta_CD$imm2 %in%('bio1','bio2') ,]
```

may be there is a better solution.

Comment: No, the values of imm1 should not be the same as the values in columns bio1 and bio2, not string "bio1". Also you are missing a c().

Comment: you mean in this way:
meta_CD <- meta_CD[(meta_CD$imm1!=meta_CD$bio1 & meta_CD$imm1!=meta_CD$bio2) | (meta_CD$imm2!=meta_CD$bio1 & meta_CD$imm2!=meta_CD$bio2),]

Comment: Thanks.  Able to run ```meta_CD <- meta_CD[! meta_CD$imm1 %in%('bio1')``` but ```meta_CD <- meta_CD[! meta_CD$imm1 %in%('bio1','bio2')``` doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Try `filter`ing in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
meta_CD %>%
  filter(! # exclude
    # Criteria A:
    (imm1==bio1|imm1==bio2|imm2==bio1|imm2==bio2
    | # or:
    # Criteria B:
    imm1==surg|imm2==surg)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

`%in%` could be used when used inside `mapply`.

```
A <- mapply(function(a, b) any(a[!is.na(a)] %in% b[!is.na(b)]),
            asplit(x[c("imm1", "imm2")], 1), asplit(x[c("bio1", "bio2")], 1))

B <- mapply(function(a, b) any(a[!is.na(a)] %in% b[!is.na(b)]),
            asplit(x[c("imm1", "imm2")], 1), asplit(x[c("surg")], 1))

x[!(A | B),]
#  Row.no imm1 imm2 bio1 bio2 surg
#3      3 2009 2009   NA   NA   NA
#4      4 2015   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Data

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Row.no   imm1    imm2    bio1    bio2    surg
1   2009    2010    2010    NA  NA
2   2004    NA  2015    NA  2004
3   2009    2009    NA  NA  NA
4   2015    NA  NA  NA  NA")
```

Comment: Tried this but comes up with: ```Error in asplit(x[c("imm1", "imm2")], 1) : 
  object 'x' not found``` and the same for B

Comment: Use instead of `x` the name of your table. E.g. `meta_CD`. Or make `x <- meta_CD` before using the given code.